# Javascript download file byte array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm calling an api and returning a byte array, name, document type and mime type of a file and trying to add Javascript to download this file.

I've all the code wired in and it downloads a file but the file is empty. I'm using the following code:

```
 result.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            var arr = data.Document;
            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arr);

            var a = window.document.createElement('a');

            a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([byteArray], { type: data.MimeType}));
            a.download = agreementId+data.DocType;

            // Append anchor to body.
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();


            // Remove anchor from body
            document.body.removeChild(a);
        });
```

I've tried the same code without the conversion to Uint8Array but this just opens a document with the binary data in it, close but not quite there. Eg I get a download of a word document that contains:
    0M8R4KGxGuEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPgADAP7/CQAGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAATwAAAAAAAAAAEAAAUQAAAAEAAAD+////AAAAAE4AAAD////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////spcEAJ2AJBAAA

ect